# Combo of IdentityHashMap and WeakHashMap

Tags: java, android, dictionary, weak-references, referenceequals

I need a `Map` implementation that shares properties of both `IdentityHashMap` and `WeakHashMap` (reference equality instead of `equals()` and weak references on keys).

What implementation do you recommend (it has to work on Android)?

Comment: `IdentityHashMap<WeakReference<K>, V>`?

Comment: @fge I was thinking that but that won't remove the key from the map when it gets collected.

Comment: @assylias uh OK, I see the problem... Then a `WeakHashMap<Equivalence.Wrapper<K>, V>` can do the trick (with `Equivalence.identity()`) but that requires Guava and inserting keys with `.wrap()`

Comment: @fge Sounds like a reasonable solution - instead of guava it could simply be `class Wrapper<T> { private final T t; public Wrapper(T t) { this.t = t;} public int hashcode() { return t.hashcode(); } public boolean equals(Object o) { return t == o; } }`

Comment: @assylias err... `return System.identityHashCode(t)`? ;)

Comment: Anyway, back to the question, why do you need that exactly?

Comment: @fge Well, it's complex: I'm implementing MVVM library for Android in parts similar to Microsoft's WPF. There is a thing called `DependencyProperty`, and containers of values for that properties are stored in a `Map`. They have to be removed from the map when `DependencyProperty` owner is collected...

Comment: @assylias It's nice solution but how do I find value for unwrapped element?

Comment: `public T get() { return t; }` ?

Comment: @assylias No but `Map`'s keys will be `Wrapper<T>` so how can I find value for unwrapped key (`T`)?

Comment: `map.get(new Wrapper(t));` should work.

Comment: To roaming programmer that my read those comments - don't use fge's solution - it WON'T work. It may look like it does but it's broken. Here is why - `WeakHashMap` will point to `Equivalence.Wrapper<K>` not `K` so keys will be removed when `Equivalence.Wrapper<K>` is collected, not when collected is `K`. `Equivalence.Wrapper<K>` might  (and very likely will) be collected while `K` still does exist.

Comment: @mrpyo This can work if the `Wrapper<K> extends WeakReference<K>`. When GC collects K, it will collect `Wrapper<K>` allowing `WeakHashMap` to remove `Map.Entry<K, V>` as usual. To your last sentence, I'm unsure how `Equivalence.Wrapper<K>` is likely to be collected when it can strongly reach `K`

Comment: @Sgene9 `Equivalence.Wrapper<K>` is likely to be collected because nothing holds strong reference to `Equivalence.Wrapper<K>` - after all you are using `WeakReference<Equivalence.Wrapper<K>>` in hash map keys and that map holds strong references to that `WeakReference<Equivalence.Wrapper<K>>` and not `Equivalence.Wrapper<K>`. But you are correct if `Equivalence.Wrapper<K>` extended `WeakReference` it could probably work.

Comment: @mrpyo Oh, I was thinking the other way around. I was focused on how to automatically remove the key. You are right that the `Equivalence.Wrapper<K>` is removed whether it extends `WeakReference` or not.

Answer (score 6):

If you're suggesting Guava, then `new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap()` would do the job directly, since `weakKeys` uses reference equality for keys.

The documentation of `weakKeys` says:

> Specifies that each key (not value) stored in the map should be wrapped in a WeakReference (by default, strong references are used).
>   Warning: when this method is used, the resulting map will use identity (==) comparison to determine equality of keys, which is a technical violation of the Map specification, and may not be what you expect.

Comment: Thanks! And what about no Guava?

Comment: Following my first comment, in the scope of an IntelliJ Plugin, I've solved with two IdentityHashMap and a Disposable hierarchical system (offered by the platform). https://github.com/lppedd/idea-conventional-commit/blob/14ae62bf034a07467f465d41e728a9b03a2cfe16/src/main/kotlin/com/github/lppedd/cc/completion/CommitCompletionContributor.kt?fbclid=IwAR0Sly65RaInSLZKXRUPHfp-irHfVAQfRvCq4GTW0SW1dZHjE6ytYjC2-do#L157-L170

Comment: If you don't want to use Guava, there is class [`WeakIdentityHashMap`](http://plumelib.org/plume-util/api/org/plumelib/util/WeakIdentityHashMap.html) in the [plume-util library](https://github.com/plume-lib/plume-util) does the same thing.